# In EXCEL 2010: How i can do conditional formating to visualize the difference of two sets of variables...?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to visualize the difference between two sets of variables e.g. I have two sets of variables Original and obtained as:

```
Original = {1, 5, 7, 9}
obtained = {2, 5, 6, 8}
```

Now, in Excel i want to visualize the difference between two sets, that means the variables are in original and also found in Obtained it can be colored in GREEN (cell color). The variables that could not find in the Obtained could be ORANGE and the additional variables could be RED.

(My algorithm use VC++ to generate "Obtained" sets, and i want to use MS Excel for conditional formatting)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you might make a hidden row somewhere with something like:

```
=IF(ISNA(HLOOKUP(A1;$A$2:$D$2;1;0));"";"+")
```

assuming that your first set is in the first row, and the second set in the second - then drag the formula along the entire row of course - remember to keep the references absolute - if you change the comparison set range.
The notation above is openoffice calc but it's much the same in MSExcel (e.g. ; -> ,).
Now you conditionally format the second row ('obtained') with the "Formula is" (not "Value is"):

```
(A3="+") 
for the positive case setting background to green and 
(A3="") 
for the negative case setting background to orange
```

Hope it helps at all.

Comment: Thank you dear, now using c++ i put signs in the front of each difference. So, how i can replace these signs with colored icons in excel, i see in excel it require integer value rather than symbol or text??

Comment: What kinds of signs? you want [<sign><obtained value>] in one cell?

Answer (score 0):

yes use Conditional formatting.

Here are some links to help you:

- [Chip Pearson (Excel MVP legend) / cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cformatting.htm)
- [Debra Dalglish (Excel MVP Legend) / Contextures.com)](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html)

that should get you started

Philip